# Wicket page like Servlet without markup

Tags: java, wicket

I need a class in wicket 1.4 that work like a Servlet but that needs access to the wicket's Session. I can use a normal WebPage but I'd prefer something more appropriate.

Comment: I mean, why to extend a WebPage if I just need to: getSession().getSomeParameterValue(); throw new RedirectToUrlException(someUrl);

Comment: at this point -4 means only "I don't know Wicket enough to help you"

Comment: Not necessarily, DeejonZ. I know this question is dead and buried, but it is perfectly acceptable to extend `WebPage`, throw a redirection exception and not provide any corresponding markup. I use this technique often to implement a logout page which has a pretty URL, invalides the session and sends a redirect, but doesn't require markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you refer to the question asked a few week ago [Wicket Session and Jersey REST webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764286/wicket-session-and-jersey-rest-webservice) you will find out how to access the Wicket session from another Servlet (in the same application).

Comment: this could be a solution, I'll try it