# How to access wicket session from Jersey-2 request filter?

Tags: spring, jersey, wicket, jersey-2.0

In Jersey 1.x we accessed the Wicket session from a (Jersey) session attribute, as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15767824/1399659.

In moving to Jersey 2.x it seems the proper pattern to use a [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html), which also allows Spring bean injection as well. We have this working successfully by including

```
<param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
```

as an init-param to the ServletContainer and using the @Provider annotation on a ContainerRequestFilter implementation. But this container filter is a singleton, and it's not possible to inject the HttpServletRequest into this (see [JERSEY-2114](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2114))

In the filter() method we have access to the [ContainerRequestContext](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) but can't access the HttpServletRequest from there.

So is there a way to either:

1. Enable Spring bean injection within a servlet filter (with Jersey too)?
2. Access the servlet request from within a ContainerRequestFilter?
3. Access wicket session from Spring-bean-aware object with Jersey filtering ability some other way?

`

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector;

@Provider
public class SecurityContextFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

//@Context
//HttpServletRequest webRequest;

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
    //HttpSession httpSession = webRequest.getSession();
    //MyWicketSession mySession = (MyWicketSession) httpSession.getAttribute("wicket:" + BaseConstants.WICKET_FILTER_NAME + ":session");
    //doAuthCheck(mySession, requestContext);
}
...
}
```

`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Fixed](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1960) in Jersey 2.4:

```
import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.ws.rs.Priorities;

@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Context
    HttpServletRequest webRequest;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        final HttpSession session = webRequest.getSession();

        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {
            @Override
            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                return new PrincipalImpl((String)session.getAttribute("USER_NAME"));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isUserInRole(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSecure() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can also register the filter without using @Provider annotation:

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;

/**
 * Root REST resource class.
 */
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RootResource  extends ResourceConfig {
    /**
     * Initializes all resources from REST package.
     */
    public RootResource() {
        packages("com.example.rest");
        register(AuthRequestFilter.class);
    }
}
```

Note: Glassfish 4.0.0 uses old Jersey 2.0.
You will have to upgrade Jersey using [these tips](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.17/glassfish.html) (it's not proven to work well). Or the better way is to download [nightly build of Glassfish 4.0.1.](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/glassfish/4.0.1/nightly/latest-glassfish.zip) but it's not completely stable at the moment. I hope the new version will be released soon.

Comment: Works a treat, thanks!
Others can note too, that if can't use `@Provider` etc annotations due to lack of support for `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` init-param (eg in WebSphere), then the same can be achieved by passing an instance of your provider class back in `getSingletons()` in your implementation of `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`

Comment: Or extend ResourceConfig and register the filter there.

Comment: My `ContainerRequestFilter` is created once during application startup, so when my `filter` method is invoked, the `HttpServletRequest` doesn't get injected. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When filter is registered as a provider, Jersey is trying to inject @Context attributes and fails because it happens outside of a request chain. How to register a filter without be a provider?

Comment: I actually upgraded Jersey as instructed and kept getting nulls for the request... it is only then that I stumbled at https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1630 that nailed the problem... it's all about the registration of your filter... if you register an instance rather than a class then the injection will fail