# How to integrate Spring Rest with Apache Wicket web application

Tags: wicket, web.xml, wicket-6, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have Apache Wiket + Spring  web application  that works without any issues .
At present Spring used DI framework and to filter Mobile access .
We are planning to use Spring Rest in our application , Can you advise me how do I do this in our existing web xml .
Initially Rest Api will be used by existing Web sessions to access data(ui pages using ajax calls ), Therefore I want Rest controllers able to access existing Wicket http session(if used logged in ) .
e.g. : rest call from existing http session should be able to access existing http session . 
Any idea ? Thanks and appriciate your time.

My idea was to use ‘`org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`’ with a 
 Tag , however my doubt is this way I want be sharing same session  ?

My existing `web.xml` (working)

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:myapp-spring-config.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>myapp</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>applicationFactoryClassName</param-name>
        <param-value>org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringWebApplicationFactory</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
   <filter-name>myappMobileRequestFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>myappMobileRequestFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
   <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
<listener-class>
    org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
</listener-class>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved for me  ! Thanks for martin-g on directing me to `WicketSessionFilter` . I m posting the answer here for future reference of any one or for suggestion(if needed)..

Changes I/We made in my '`web.xml`' addition to above posted `web.xml`.

```
  <filter>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.servlet.WicketSessionFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>filterName</param-name>
            <param-value>myapp</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

As you can see I have added a `WicketSessionFilter` to to filter `/rest/*` requests which consume by spring  consume by spring `DispatcherServlet`.

and if you want to access spring session in Spring rest controller all you have to do is below
e.g :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/service")
public class TestServiceController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/getValue/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public String getValue(@PathVariable String name,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

      HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
      WebSession wicketSession = session.getAttribute("wicket:wicket.myapp:session");

          //rest of the code here ........
                 return result;
     }
```

And Spring-rest & Wicket lived happily ever after ....

Comment: Also credit goes to this post too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764286/wicket-session-and-jersey-rest-webservice

Answer (score 1):

Since both Wicket's Filter and Spring's Servlet are in the same web.xml then they will share the same **javax.servlet.HttpSession**. If you need to be able to reach Wicket's **org.apache.wicket.Session** in Spring's REST handlers then you will need to setup Wicket's WicketSessionFilter [1].

1. https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/8d23f188e8509e4fae945bbfb9710c489c57423c/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/servlet/WicketSessionFilter.java

Comment: Thanks martin-g , do i need at add 'org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet' to web.xml ? because
i tried doing that , however still i cant see  my controller mapping using spring @RestController getting triggered , am i missing something here ..